# Where are the VBProjectsEvents?

Tags: c#, events, com-interop, vbe

Using `Microsoft.Vbe.Interop` in C#, I can access `CommandBarEvents` and `ReferencesEvents` via `VBE.Events`.

However the ever-so helpful [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263158(v=vs.60).aspx) documentation seems to indicate that there's a `VBProjectsEvents` that I could use to notify my add-in when a project is added or removed to/from the VBE... which is exactly what I'm trying to achieve here.

I can see that `_VBProjectsEvents` interface in the *object browser*, but no implementation for it (as opposed to the `_CommandBarControlsEvents` interface, which is implemented by the `CommandBarEventsClass`), using ReSharper's *go to implementation* feature.

Is there an implementation of the `_VBProjectsEvents` interface anywhere? If not, then how does one go about being notified of a VBProject being removed from the IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a *sink* for these events.

Implement the `_dispVBProjectsEvents` dispatch interface - here's an implementation that responds to these events by invoking regular managed .net events, effectively "wrapping" the `VBProjects` events:

```
public class VBProjectsEventsSink : _dispVBProjectsEvents
{
    public event EventHandler<DispatcherEventArgs<VBProject>> ProjectAdded;
    public void ItemAdded(VBProject VBProject)
    {
        if (VBProject.Protection == vbext_ProjectProtection.vbext_pp_none)
        {
            OnDispatch(ProjectAdded, VBProject);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<DispatcherEventArgs<VBProject>> ProjectRemoved;
    public void ItemRemoved(VBProject VBProject)
    {
        if (VBProject.Protection == vbext_ProjectProtection.vbext_pp_none)
        {
            OnDispatch(ProjectRemoved, VBProject);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<DispatcherRenamedEventArgs<VBProject>> ProjectRenamed;
    public void ItemRenamed(VBProject VBProject, string OldName)
    {
        var handler = ProjectRenamed;
        if (handler != null && VBProject.Protection == vbext_ProjectProtection.vbext_pp_none)
        {
            handler.Invoke(this, new DispatcherRenamedEventArgs<VBProject>(VBProject, OldName));
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<DispatcherEventArgs<VBProject>> ProjectActivated;
    public void ItemActivated(VBProject VBProject)
    {
        if (VBProject.Protection == vbext_ProjectProtection.vbext_pp_none)
        {
            OnDispatch(ProjectActivated, VBProject);
        }
    }

    private void OnDispatch(EventHandler<DispatcherEventArgs<VBProject>> dispatched, VBProject project)
    {
        var handler = dispatched;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler.Invoke(this, new DispatcherEventArgs<VBProject>(project));
        }
    }
}
```

The `DispatcherEventArgs` class is just a convenient way to expose the `VBProject` item involved with the event, and it can be reused for other sinks:

```
public class DispatcherEventArgs<T> : EventArgs 
    where T : class
{
    private readonly T _item;

    public DispatcherEventArgs(T item)
    {
        _item = item;
    }

    public T Item { get { return _item; } }
}
```

The client code needs to register the sink - and for that you need to keep an `IConnectionPoint` field and its `int` cookie:

```
private readonly IConnectionPoint _projectsEventsConnectionPoint;
private readonly int _projectsEventsCookie;
```

The `VBProjects` collection implements the `IConnectionPointContainer` interface, which you need to use to *find the connection point*:

```
var sink = new VBProjectsEventsSink();
var connectionPointContainer = (IConnectionPointContainer)_vbe.VBProjects;
var interfaceId = typeof (_dispVBProjectsEvents).GUID;
connectionPointContainer.FindConnectionPoint(ref interfaceId, out _projectsEventsConnectionPoint);
```

Once you have the `IConnectionPoint`, use the `Advise` method to "connect" your sink and retrieve a *cookie*:

```
_projectsEventsConnectionPoint.Advise(sink, out _projectsEventsCookie);
```

And then you can handle the sink events as you would any "normal" .net events:

```
sink.ProjectAdded += sink_ProjectAdded;
sink.ProjectRemoved += sink_ProjectRemoved;
sink.ProjectActivated += sink_ProjectActivated;
sink.ProjectRenamed += sink_ProjectRenamed;
```

When you want to disconnect your sink, you pass the *cookie* to the `Unadvise` method of the `IConnectionPoint` instance:

```
_projectsEventsConnectionPoint.Unadvise(_projectsEventsCookie);
```

"Simple as that!"

Comment: Are you aware of any events to track the opening and closing of CodePane objects?  I posted a new question here: [Event raised when closing or opening a CodePane](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44391917/154439).